# How can I get file name and put It in TextEdit

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have a Text Edit and a Button in my example. I can get file by using File Dialog. I don't know how to put file name or file path into Text Edit, I tried to use `substring` but it not work well, how can I do that?

This is my code:

```
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick 2.6

// This is rectangle parent
Rectangle {
    id: overlay
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    color: "#000000"

   // EditText into Rectangle
   // rec edit tex
   Rectangle{
        id:rectextbox
        width: 150
        height: 22
        anchors.top: recmidle.top
        anchors.topMargin: 39
        anchors.left: recmidle.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 24
        TextEdit{
            id: txtedit
            width: rectextbox.width
            height: rectextbox.height
            anchors.verticalCenter: rectextbox.verticalCenter
            anchors.horizontalCenter: rectextbox.horizontalCenter
        }
    }

        // Using FileDialog to get file
        FileDialog {
        id: file
        title: "Choose an image"
    }

    // Button to find and search file
    Button{
        id: btnput
        width: 50
        height: 22
        background: Rectangle{
            id: btnrtg1
            color: "#737373"
        }
        anchors.top: recmidle.top
        anchors.topMargin: 39
        anchors.right: recmidle.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 76
        Text {
            id: textname1
            anchors.verticalCenter: recbutton1.verticalCenter
            anchors.horizontalCenter: recbutton1.horizontalCenter
            text: qsTr("get image")
            color: "white"
        }

        // MouseArea to set event Onclick for FileDialog
        MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: file.visible = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could show your united code, if it is separated it is confusing.

Comment: Yes, agree with @eyllanesc. Please unite your code, add those extra lines as comment in that code

Comment: Thanks for advise @eyllanesc, I was united code as you said. Thanks you

Comment: try to add this handler to  your `FileDialog` - `onAccepted: txtedit.text = file.fileUrl`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add an handler to your `FileDialog` :

```
FileDialog {
        id: file
        title: "Choose an image"
        onAccepted: txtedit.text = fileUrl.toString().replace('file:///','')
}
```